# Airflow Time Delta Sensor behaviour with manual run

Tags: airflow-scheduler, airflow

How does Airflow's built-in Time Delta Sensor behave as part of a manually triggered DAG run?

https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/airflow/sensors/time_delta_sensor.html

"Waits for a timedelta after the task's execution_date + schedule_interval"

If I trigger a DAG containing this sensor manually, the Time Delta Sensor seems to sit there indefinitely, never completing. It does complete as expected from a scheduled DAG run.

How is this sensor supposed to behave in a manual run?

Is this behaviour due to the "execution_date + schedule_interval" mentioned in the docs there? If so, what does that mean exactly?

Comment: It does seem that execution_date + schedule_interval is the reason for TimeDeltaSensor to seemingly wait indefinitely.  If your schedule interval is one day then it would wait for 1 day + the time delta you specified.